# (HTML/PHP) Drop down menu selection affect a table and a form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm making a DB for personnel administration, there is a page where you can enter all education record (school, high school, college, etc...) and I got this form

```
<form name="form2" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
<table  id="rounded-corner" width="85%" border="0">
          <tr>
            <th width="20%" ><p>Start Date</p></th>
            <th width="20%" ><p>End Date</p></th>
            <th width="20%" ><p>Institution Name</p></th>
            <th width="20%" ><p>Intitution Type</p></th>
            <th width="10%" ><p>Actions</p></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="CI" id="CI" autocomplete="off" required value="<?php echo $data1['CI']; ?>"/>
            <select name="instype">
    <?php
    $sql3=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM institutionslist");
    while($datalt1=mysql_fetch_array($sql3))
    {
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $datalt1['InstituteType'] ?>"><?php echo $datalt1['InstituteType'] ?>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Institute" id="Institute" size="2px" maxlength="2px" autocomplete="off" required value=""/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="FdID" id="FdID" size="2px" maxlength="2px" autocomplete="off" required value=""/>
            <input type="text" name="FdIM" id="FdIM" size="2px" maxlength="2px" autocomplete="off" required value=""/>
            <input type="text" name="FdIA" id="FdIA" size="3px" maxlength="4px" autocomplete="off" required value=""/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="FdCD" id="FdCD" size="2px" maxlength="2px"autocomplete="off" required value=""/>
            <input type="text" name="FdCM" id="FdCM" size="2px" maxlength="2px" autocomplete="off" required value=""/>
            <input type="text" name="FdCA" id="FdCA" size="3px" maxlength="4px" autocomplete="off" required value=""/></td>
            <td align="center">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-mini"><i class="icon-ok"></i></button> 
            </td>
          </tr>
```

I want it so that, for example, if I select "University" in the Drop Down Menu, I get an extra column on the table with a textbox and the header "Degree Obtained", but it would only show with University selected, is it possible to do this WITHOUT Java/Jscript/Ajax/Anything related to Java? and instead html/php

Comment: Nope. You would have to use javascript. Or you would have to submit the form then have it show. Why are you trying to avoid javascript?

Comment: AFAIK Javascript is not related to JAVA!

Comment: I hate jscript :/ the whole page is also coded in php/html and this one would be the only section to use it, thanks for the answer.

Comment: If you at all serious about doing any type of web development you are going to need to learn and use javascript.

Comment: Eventually, yes, but not now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could only do it with PHP if you had the choice, on select, serve to a new page that reloaded, because PHP all happens BEFORE the page is created...but that would be very slow and not at all a good user experience.  It's not possible with PHP because by the time the page is visible to the end user, there's no live code or interaction from PHP.  Javascript or jQuery would be my suggestion, since they reside client-side, in the browser, and can thus "listen" for events like a user selecting a form.

Doing it with Javascript isn't very difficult:  you just have a class for the hidden form elements and use Javascript to change the "display" value to "block" after the user clicks a choice.

I hope that's helpful!  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I just talked with my supervisor and it turns out all of the institutions will use the same fields, so I don't have to do that, thanks anyways!